# What does everyone have running in their cron?

Tags: security, cron, maintenance, crontab

In cron I run a bunch of regular maintenance stuff on my production server.

I was wondering what everyone else runs in theirs.  Is there anything novel?  Is there anything very basic that noobs typically leave out?

Please share :)

Answer (score 2):

Crontabs are likely to be as diverse and unique as the operating system's users.  There's no "standard" crontab.  However, certain software packages may add crontab entries to perform periodic tasks, such as Webmin.

Here's some interesting things I use cron for:

- Reboot wireless router daily at 5:30am
- Update various web-accessible HTML status pages every 5 minutes
- Call script to backup /etc directory to a USB drive nightly

Answer (score 2):

I only use it to call `rsync` to back up files from one hard drive to another.